# TypeError: d.$$minErr is not a function in angular-route.min.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error: "TypeError: d.$$minErr is not a function". It seems to be a problem with angular-route.

My code:
index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">
    <head>        
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <search-result></search-result>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){ 
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

});

// controllers

myApp.directive('searchResult', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'AECM',
       templateUrl: 'customDirectivePage.html',
       replace: true
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you add plunker with error?

Comment: With plunker, do you mean this?

Comment: yes, you can create there simple example with error.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/L1BDaRmnPCfTemG6lSiu?p=preview

Comment: @milanlempera: The save feature faild somehow. Maybe you can access it for colloboration: 2uTt6K3n389u5Pjb

Comment: your plunker does not contain angular and another files. But i thing problem is in version. Which version of angular and router you use?

Comment: @milanlempera http://plnkr.co/edit/L1BDaRmnPCfTemG6lSiu?p=catalogue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is working example http://plnkr.co/edit/ML2XJxUhWPvym1mYwVCZ?p=preview

I think, you have incompatible versions of angular and angular-router.
Versions of both should be same.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
```